# On quintic roots $x_1^{1/5}+x_2^{1/5}+\dots+x_5^{1/5}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory, fields

(*Major revision to incorporate new results in this MO [cubic version](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243685/an-elliptic-curve-for-ramanujan-type-cubic-identities).*)

**Note:** All coefficients are in the rationals.

> **I. Cubic**

In the linked post, it was shown that given a general cubic (via its depressed form),

$$x^3+px+q=0\tag1$$

and its roots $x_i$, then it is possible to find infinitely many rational $u$,

$$G_3 := (u \pm x_1)^{1/3}+ (u \pm x_2)^{1/3}+ (u \pm x_3)^{1/3}  = {v}^{1/3}\tag2$$

such that $v$ is also a cubic root or even rational. Apparently, a necessary but not sufficient condition is that $u$ should be a rational point on,

$$u^3+pu+q=w^3\tag3$$

which, after a transformation, is an elliptic curve.

> **II. Quartic**

By analogy, the quartic version should be,

$$G_4:=(u +x_1)^{1/4}+ (u +x_2)^{1/4}+ (u +x_3)^{1/4}+(u+x_4)^{1/4} = {v}^{1/4}\tag4$$

where the $x_i$ are the four solutions of a quartic and $v$ is ***at most*** a quartic root. By trial and error, I found the equation,

$$x^4+x^3+\big(\tfrac{n-3}{2}\big)^2x^2+x+1=0\tag5$$

and using $u=0$, then the $RHS$ of $(4)$ is $v=t^2$ which is a root of,

$$(t^2 - 8t + 6 - n)^2 = 4 n t^2\tag6$$

Thus $v$ is a quartic but, by judicious choice of $n$, can be a quadratic or even just a linear root.

> **Example:**

Let $n=81$, then we have the irreducible,

$$x^4 + x^3 + 1521x^2 + x + 1=0$$

with complex roots $x_{1,2} \approx -0.49\pm38.99i$, and $x_{3,4} \approx -0.0003\pm0.025i$. Let $u=0$ in $(4)$ then,

$$x_1^{1/4}+x_2^{1/4}+x_3^{1/4}+x_4^{1/4} = (225)^{1/4}$$

or,

$$x_1^{1/4}+x_2^{1/4}+x_3^{1/4}+x_4^{1/4} = (413+52\sqrt{61})^{1/4}$$

depending on the $4$th roots used.

> **III. Quintic**

**Question:** Is it possible to find a class of quintics that is  ***irreducible*** (over $\mathbb{Q}$) yet have roots $x_i$ such that,

$$G_5:=x_1^{1/5}+x_2^{1/5}+\dots+x_5^{1/5} = v^{1/5}$$

and $v$ at most is a root of a quintic also with rational coefficients, or is there something in Galois theory that may be an obstruction?

Comment: Your use of "degree of an algebraic number" is inconsistent.  I guess you mean that number generate an extension of that degree, so you should say $F_3$ is a priori of degree at most or dividing 9, and similarly for $F_5$.  Also, maybe it would be helpful to say what you tried.  Did you try a computer search?  Roots of quintics seem complicated to me, and this is what I would suggest.

Comment: So you're looking for
something like the roots of $x^5 + 6x^4 - x^3 - 32x^2 + 16x - 1$ 
(which are in ${\bf Q}(\cos \pi/11)$ and have fifth roots that sum to 
$v^{1/5}$ with $v^5 - 1370v^4 + 518385v^3 + 319010v^2 + 143005v + 1 = 0$)?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: Yes, great result! I've elaborated on your comment and gave more details as an answer below. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: I thought you wanted me to post an answer including an explanation of why these identities exist.  And yes, as I wrote in e-mail there are similar things for 7th roots and beyond, in fields with either a cyclic Galois group (such as the one contained in ${\bf Q}(\cos 2\pi/29)$) or dihedral Galois (I gave the examples of $x^5 + x^4 - 3x^3 - 3x^2 + 4x - 1$ and $x^7 - 26x^6 + 350x^5 - 2192x^4 + 6287x^3 - 6718x^2 - 162x - 1$ in the same email).

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: Oops, I just saw your email. I've deleted my answer, and I'll wait for the one you planned that explains the general case. My sincere apologies.

Comment: No problem, and no need to apologize...

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: Ok. And thanks again for that quintic. I've been looking for something like it for more than two years already, as in this [MSE post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612607/what-comes-after-cos-tfrac2-pi71-3-cos-tfrac4-pi71-3-cos).

Comment: You're welcome.  Meanwhile, the number you ask about in that post (fifth power of $\sum_{n=1}^5 \cos(2\pi n/11)^{1/5}$) is indeed of degree $125$; if you really need to see the polynomial I can send you the paragraph of **gp** code . . .

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: I'm afraid I'm not that familiar with gp. However, if you wish, you can answer that MSE question using that code. But only if you want to. I'm just happy to know its exact degree after wondering about it for years.

Comment: @Noam D. Elkies I really need to see this polynomial. Can you send me the paragraph of gp code ?

Comment: What's your e-mail address (and why do you "really need to see" it)?

Comment: Come to think of it there's no need because the code's short enough.  (I doubled the roots to make them algebraic integers, so the polynomial is in ${\bf Z}[x]$.)$$ $$ **default(realprecision,500);
v=2 * vector(5,n,cos(Pi*n/5.5));
for(n=1,5,v[n]=sign(v[n]) * abs(v[n])^(1/5));
z=exp(Pi * I/2.5);
P=1;
for(a=0,4,for(b=0,4,for(c=0,4,P *= x-(v * [z^a,z^b,z^c,z^(-a-b-c),1]~)^5)));
round(P)**

Comment: @ Noam D. Elkies Thank you, Noam. I checked some (perhaps interesting) heuristic facts. Let me try to explain what I mean. Let $p \equiv 1 \bmod 5$ be a prime number, and $g$ a primitive root modulo $p$. Put
$$ S_1(g):= \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{p-6}5}\cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{p}g^{5k}\right) , S_2(g):= \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{p-6}5}\cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{p}g^{5k+1}\right) , S_3(g):= \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{p-6}5}\cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{p}g^{5k+2}\right) ,\\
S_4(g):= \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{p-6}5}\cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{p}g^{5k+3}\right) ,
S_5(g):= \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{p-6}5}\cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{p}g^{5k+4}\right) .$$

Comment: It can be shown that $$s:=\left(\sqrt[5]{S_1(g)} +  \sqrt[5]{S_2(g)} +  \sqrt[5]{S_3(g)}  +  \sqrt[5]{S_4(g)}  +  \sqrt[5]{S_5(g)} \right)^5$$ is an algebraic integer, and let $f(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $s$. Then, as I have checked for $p=11,31,41,61,71,101,131,151,181,191$, we have $f(x)\equiv {x^5}^l +1 \bmod 5$, where $l$ equals $3$ or $4$.

Comment: For instance, taking $p=11$ we obtain $$\left \{ S_1(g),S_2(g),S_3(g),S_4(g),S_5(g) \right \} =\\ \left \{ 2 \cos\frac{2\pi}{11},2 \cos\frac{4\pi}{11},  2 \cos\frac{6\pi}{11}, 2 \cos\frac{8\pi}{11},2 \cos\frac{10\pi}{11}\right \}$$
and $f(x)=x^{125} + 15125x^{124}+ \ldots \equiv x^{125}+1 \bmod 5$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies I revisited this by connecting it to the Emma Lehmer quintic. Care to take a peek at this [new MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4737700/4781)?